# Что такое RET и как он влияет на вывод

Tags: linux

Нашел книгу Linux cookbook. Некоторые команды там идут с суффиксом RET, например w RET. Причем вывод с RET и без него разный. Что такое RET и для чего он нужен?

Comment: Невнимательно читали, в самом начале Linux cookbook об этом написано, всего лишь обозначение нажатия клавиши перевода строки

Comment: Сокращение от “RETurn” или «Возврат Каретки» (на русских клавиатурах ВК, а в простонародье “Enter”).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Невнимательно читали, в самом начале Linux cookbook об этом написано, всего лишь обозначение нажатия клавиши перевода строки

Сокращение от “RETurn” или «Возврат Каретки» (на русских клавиатурах ВК, а в простонародье “Enter”).

Comment: "общий" ответ из коментариев. Раз не удалили вопрос - пусть будет и ответ